# SimpleDialog2 jQuery Mobile checkbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have this code to show a popup with a checkbox, and I want when I click on the checkbox that triggers an alert with a value of the checkbox. How can I do this?

```
$('<div>').simpledialog2({
            mode: 'blank',
            headerText: 'Crate',
            headerClose: true,
            blankContent : 
                '<div data-role="fieldcontain">'+
                '<fieldset data-role="controlgroup"><legend>Select:</legend><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1a" id="checkbox-1a" class="custom" /><label for="checkbox-1a">Cheetos</label></fieldset>'+
                '</div>'+
                '<a rel="close" data-role="button" href="#" id="submit">Submit</a>'
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly (you want an alert to be displayed whenever someone clicks on the checkbox), just put this within the javascript tag in the head:

```
$('#checkbox-1a').click(function () {    
    alert(this.checked);
});
```